# Why nginx doesn't do simple load balancing. Tomcat instances. Bad request 400

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I stuck with a simple task. 
I have Tomcat cluster of 3 instances available on:

> IP = 10.0.0.136 (IP of my machine); Ports = 8180; 8280; 8380;

Then I run nginx with the following **nginx.conf**:

```
http {
    upstream tomcat_servers {
        server 10.0.0.136:8180;
        server 10.0.0.136:8280;
        server 10.0.0.136:8380;
    }
...

server {
        listen       8011;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://tomcat_servers;       
        }
```

My Tomcat instances up and running, I can check them in my browser and they show Tomcat's starting page.

However when I come to nginx on **localhost:8011** there is Bad Request 400 HTTP status.
In logs there are also no errors... I have already restarted nginx, just in case.

This error I get on Mac and Linux Ubuntu.

What I have missed?

The response of nginx:
[image]

In error.log there are no errors.

access.log:
[image]

Comment: `nginx -t` to confirm no errors? What do the access logs say?

Comment: @ShawnC. nothing in access logs, however in error.log - [error] 7852#7856: OpenEvent("Global\ngx_stop_5388") failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: FYI: https://nick.zoic.org/art/nginx-django-400-bad-request/ for an explanation of why "_" fails. In summary the Host headers is rewritten by nginx and in this case, Tomcat requires it to be valid according to RFC 952.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the issue... it is strange however when I use this:

```
upstream tomcats {...} //in proxy_pass also of course
```

**without sign "_"** then all works perfect. I suspected that it might be some my mistake on writing and used simple:

```
upstream a_b {...}
```

and also received 400 bad request.

So I don't know why it is so, however this resolve the issue.

I use *Ubuntu 18.04* and *nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)*